# Amazon Affiliate search using a movie title

Tags: api, affiliate, amazon

I am currently working on a movie trailer site. I have over 300 movies and I do not want to add an amazon affiliate link to each one individually.

Does amazon offer any sort of api that will allow me to use a movie title to search for a dvd on amazon?

Ex. For the movie skyfall, the amazon affiliate link would be `amazon.com/search/dvd/skyfall/affiliate`id

^ I just made the link up as i don't know how their system works, but I just want it to do a search on the movie title

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is called the Product Advertising API, specifically the ItemSearch - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemSearch.html

This should help you get a set of product given the title of movie, the category [DVD], etc.